# Connection refused by proxy configuration

Tags: java, apache, proxy

I am trying to code a program to use REST services of a provider.

My problem is that there is a proxy with user/password authentication, and I am not able to fix that issue.

It works without using a proxy, but I need to use proxy.

That is my code without proxy configuration.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class callAPI {

public callAPI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException {

    //System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(
            "URL");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
            .getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = "";

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);

    }

}

}
```

I´ve read all posts and tried to do that in my code but always get the same error (connection refused).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the example [Apache doco](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java)

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 443, "https");
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(proxy)
            .build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");
request.setConfig(config);

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);
```

You can also try adding

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Comment: I get  " java.net.UnknownHostException" but the uri is right. If I try it from a web browser I can access to the service. In that example user/password is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "ProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "ProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "UserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "Password");
```